# Add record Progressive Number after tUnite component

Tags: etl, talend, data-integration

I have the following issue: I am taking records from several tables and then I combine them with tUnite component in order to create a .txt file. After that I sort retrieved rows based on a certain field. The output file is like this:

```
                   myField              
HeaderRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   empty   -> field I want to calculate for Additional Record
DetailRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   empty   -> field I want to calculate for Additional Record
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   empty   -> field I want to calculate for Additional Record
```

What I want to do is to calculate "myField" just for "AddionalRecord" (TAB3). This Field is a Progressive number which must works like showed in the screenshot below.

How can I achieve my goal after I merge records with tUnite?

```
                   myField              
HeaderRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   000000004   -> field I want to calculate for Additional Record
DetailRecord       xxxxx
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   000000007
DetailRecord       xxxxx
AdditionalRecord   000000009
```

I attached myJob below:

[image]

Does anyone could help me? Thank you in advance.

[image]

It seems I cannot read the value of row6.message_type_id

Comment: You could add tMap and and call calculateMyField() function only if inputRow.column1.equals("AdditionalRecord")

Comment: I exactly did this. I add a tMap after tUnite_1 and then put a condition in myField as showned below:

Comment: And what's the pb now? Does it work?

Comment: No, It does not work. The condition does not reading the value of row6.message_type_id

Comment: Could you please add error you have? (Is it compile error or what)

Comment: It compile without errors and it runs. It just does not consider the value of row6.message_type_id in the condition

Comment: Try to compare strings with !row6.message_type_id.equals("0100"), instead of `!=`